# How to `pip install` a package that has non-Python dependencies?

Tags: python, pip

Many python packages have build dependencies on non-Python packages. I'm specifically thinking of lxml and cffi, but this dilemma applies to a lot of packages on PyPI. Both of these packages have unadvertised build dependencies on non-Python packages like libxml2-dev, libxslt-dev, zlib1g-dev, and libffi-dev. The websites for lxml and cffi declare some of these dependencies, but it appears that there is no way to do figure this out from a command line.

As a result, there are hundreds of questions on SO that take this general form:

> `pip install foo` fails with an error: "fatal error: bar.h: No such file or directory". How do I fix it?

Is this a misuse of `pip` or is this *how it is intended to work?* Is there a sane way to know what build dependencies to install before running `pip`? My current approach is:

1. I want to install a package called `foo`.
2. `pip install foo`
3. `foo` has a dependency on a Python package `bar`.

   - If `bar` build fails, then look at error message and guess/google what non-Python dependency I need to install.
   - `sudo apt-get install libbaz-dev`
   - `sudo pip install bar`
   - Repeat until `bar` succeeds.
4. `sudo pip uninstall foo`
5. Repeat entire process until no error messages.

Step #4 is particularly annoying. Apparently `pip` (version 1.5.4) installs the requested package first, *before any dependencies*. So if any dependencies fail, you can't just ask `pip` to install it again, because it thinks its already installed. There's also no option to install just the dependencies, so you must uninstall the package and then reinstall it.

Is there some more intelligent process for using `pip`?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, this is why there are so many python package managers for the scientific world.  (E.g. "python distribution" package managers like `conda` & `enpkg`, setuptools replacements such as `bento`, and a bunch of lesser-known ones that I'm forgetting)  On Windows or OSX, a package maintainer can distribute a binary wheel with all the necessary libraries, but on linux/BSD systems, it's harder to guarantee what compiler the system python was built with. At any rate, as far as I know, there's no way to specify external dependencies in the distutils metadata.

Comment: I think part of the problem is also inherent in the way operating systems and dynamic linkers work.  Ideally, you'd like to take advantage of shared libraries in an OS to be more efficient with memory and such.  However, you can only install shared libraries with the system package manager since every other package in the same release cycle depends on a certain, agreed-upon version.  Because of this, there can't really be a reliable interface between pip and apt since pip has no concept of release cycles.

Comment: Debian's choice to *not* ship header files with the shared libraries by default is one of the reasons I shun anything Debian-related. There's no such thing as "quickly compiling something" on Debian, since you're always hunting for `-dev` packages; this problem is not restricted to `pip`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Fine-grained control over what installing a package pulls in is a feature, not a bug.  I don't think it would be very hard to write a wrapper to always pull in a `-dev` package if there is one.

Comment: @tripleee We are talking about a few header files ...

Comment: [`libquantlib0-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libquantlib0-dev) is 75 megs.  `apt-cache show '.*-dev$' | awk '/^Package:/ { p=$2 } /^Installed-Size:/ { print $2 "\t" p }' | sort -rn`

Comment: @tripleee Are those 75M of header files? No. We are talking about 6M of header files. The rest are some binaries are statically linked binaries, I never advocated including those. If you have a system where 6M is an issue, you're probably using a custom build anyway (since binary packages don't offer a lot of fine grained control in the first place). The *average* size seems to be about 0.35M per package (on my system, dividing the size of `/usr/include` by the total amount of installed packages).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually a comment about the answer suggesting using `apt-get` but I don't have enough reputation points to leave one.

If you use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) a lot, then installing the python-packages through `apt-get` can become a pain, as you can get mysterious errors when the python packages installed system-wide and the python packages installed in your virtualenv try to interact with each other. One thing that I have found that does help is to use the `build-dep` feature. To build the matplotlib dependencies, for example:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

And then activate your virtual environment and do `pip install matplotlib`. It will still go through the build process but many of the dependencies will be taken care of for you.

This is sort what the [cran repositories](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) suggest when installing R packages in ubuntu.

Comment: I think you should just rework this into a stand alone answer, it's pretty great.

Comment: Agree with Travis; this is a clever answer that I had never thought of.

Answer (score 1):

For most popular packages, There is a workaround for recent ubuntu systems. For example, I want to install `matplotlib`. When you order `pip install matplotlib`, it usually fails because of a missing dependency.

You can use `apt-get install python-matplotlib` instead. For python3, you can use `apt-get install python3-matplotlib`

Comment: What about installing a package into a virtual environment?

Comment: @alecxe I have no idea. I don't see anyway to use my suggestion for virtual environments.

Comment: There are two problems with this approach: (1) most ubuntu packages lag very far behind their PyPI counterparts, and (2) `pip` doesn't know anything about your APT packages, so I if `apt-get install python-matplotlib` and then later try to `pip install` something that depends on `matplotlib`, `pip` will try to install `matplotlib` again. I think it's better to use all APT or all `pip`; combining the two is just inviting future confusion and frustration.